# Can I get vbscript to show a friendly error message?

Tags: vbscript

I'm installing a network printers using vbscript and I want to show a friendly error if the queue doesn't exist or the printer server is unavailable, can I do this with VBScript? My code is below.

```
Dim net
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
net.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\printsrv\HPLaser23"
net.SetDefaultPrinter "\\printsrv\HPLaser23"
```

Many thanks for the help

Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line:

```
On Error Resume Next ' the script will "ignore" any errors
```

Before your code

and then do an:

```
if  Err.Number <> 0  then 
     ' report error in some way
end if
On Error GoTo 0 ' this will reset the error handling to normal
```

After your code

It's normally best to try to keep the number of lines of code between the `On Error Resume Next` and the `On Error GoTo 0` to as few as possible, since it's seldom good to ignore errors.